# Limit Javascript script Internet access

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with a master script that connects, via AJAX, to a remote server and downloads unsecure JS scripts (let's call them slave scripts), to be executed lately on the client. I would like to limit the Internet access slave scripts have; e.g. they can communicate just with the remote server.

Do you have any idea of how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Laurențiu Dascălu

Comment: For better answers, it might help if you say why you need this requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

JavaScript AJAX calls will have access to whatever the browser has access to.

Your best bet would be attempt to create a third JavaScript component to proxy the slave script calls through. That component would be responsible for ensuring that the slave scripts weren't calling any URLs that they shouldn't be.

The downside, of course, is that anybody can download and modify all of your scripts anyway...which means that any proxy would be easy to overcome.

Comment: If the slave scripts are long running tasks, your idea executes the same work two times, right?

Comment: @LaurențiuDascălu - No. The only thing the proxy does is check to make sure the call is going to an authorized domain...it doesn't make the call a second time.

Comment: I see, sounds like a good idea! But, how can I force the clients to use that proxy? Suppose that I know nothing about my clients.

Comment: OK, I'll force the slave clients to make all the calls in a proxy server.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/).  It can convert untrusted Javascript into safe Javascript which can only access specific resources as defined by you.

Answer (score 1):

Run the scripts in an iframe hosted on a different domain, and the browser same-origin security policy should make it more secure.